# how to change the title of tag page?

Tags: title, rewrite-tag

what is the correct function or hook to change the title of tag page ?
I want to insert something at the beginning the tag title page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_the_archive_title` filter, such as:

```
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', function($title) {
  if(is_tag()) {
    /* logic to set $title to what you want */
  }
  return $title;
});
```

Take a look at [get_the_archive_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/) reference for more information on how to use this filter.